# Add yaml parse to php.ini file using docker

Tags: php, docker, yaml, lumen

I'm trying to add `yaml_parse_file` extension on my `docker` container. 
On the `Dockerfile` I add this line to add the extension on the `php.ini` file:

```
echo 'extension=yaml.so' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

But when I run `docker-compose build` I get this warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/yaml.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/yaml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

When I'm trying to use `yaml_parse()` function I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function yaml_parse() ...

What I'm trying to do is to read a `yaml` file inside a controller from a `Lumen` project.

How can I enable `yaml_parse_file` extension using `docker`?

Answer (score 3):

This PECL extension is not bundled with PHP, see more http://php.net/manual/en/yaml.installation.php.
Just adding `extension=yaml.so` in your `php.ini` doesn't help you. You must install the PECL extenstion properly, e.g. if you use ubuntu image

```
    $ sudo apt-get install php-pear libyaml-dev
    $ sudo pecl install yamL
    $ sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=yaml.so' >> /etc/php5/mods-available/yaml.ini"
    $ sudo php5enmod yaml
```